Help! I need to fix leaky cracks in basement floor
I live in 130-year-old house with a stone walled basement. The basement walls don't currently leak, but I have some floor cracks that have started to leak a lot when there's a heavy rain. Some of the floor cracks are hairline, and some arè slightly wider. (And BTW, I am working on making sure that rainwater drains away from my house.)
Now for my question: What is the best fix for the floor cracks?
个
2
•

Having rain water drain away from the is good.  There are a number of products to fix/cover cracks.  It might not be enough to prevent the flooding.  You might want to look into sump pumps/pits and drain pipes to remove the ground water from under the floor for a long term fix.

Ground water level is high

You do not have enough info to answer this.   Is the basement finished or have living space?    What does the outside of the house look like?    Remember if you fix water from coming in, in one place, it will come in another.

High ground water level has to be addressed.
It could come from anywhere depending on the slope. There are a number of products to fix/cover cracks however that might be only short term solution.
It might not be enough to prevent the flooding.
Consider a sump pumps/pits and drain pipes around the foundation to remove the ground water from under the floor for a long term fix.

Nature has an infinite amount of water to flood your basement with.
The single best solution to basement flooding is to prevent the water from getting to your walls and floor BEFORE it gets there.
Good drainage comes first.
Make sure all your roof has gutters free of obstruction and your downspouts drain as far away from the house as practicable.
If you have a water table high enough to come up through the floor with proper drainage then anything you patch the cracks with will eventually fail.
You would then need to install a sump pump and possibly perimeter drain around the outside of the house. This requires re-excavating the outside of the house to the footing and installing a proper footing drain. A very expensive solution. But a solution.
Anything installed inside the basement allows the water to penetrate the walls or floor and then be channeled to a sump and pumped away from the house. This will last for decades but the concrete  will eventually be affected by the constant exposure to water.
Lastly, if you have moisture penetrating your basement you should never use plastic sheeting behind a wood framed wall as it just traps the moisture and promotes the growth of mold.
Solving wet basement problems in older homes is a challenge. Good luck! 
